# jQuery is not picking up correct values from a Div Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, selection

I want to pick up the values in a Div tag like which is some what like this

```
<html>
<head> </head>
<body>
<div id="page">
                <html>
                <head></head>
                <body> Hellow World </body>
                </html>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to select the content inside a div tag .

```
var msg = $("#page").html();
alert(msg);
```

this code is not working . i want that whole 2nd page along with the HTML tag is copied. How do i do that ?

I want the output to be the WHOLE thing INCLUDING the HTML tags

Comment: The problem here is you're breaking how the DOM works, then expecting javascript to work. I don't think this one will ever work reliably.

Comment: It should work. Do you have this call inside of a `$(document).ready` function? It maybe the page isn't complete when you call the alert. Do you get anything from the alert at all?

Comment: After rereading your question, I am not certain if I understood it correctly. Are you looking for a string representation of the html code inside the #page div? If so, you are probably going to run into problems because some of the elements within the #page div cannot be inside themselves. Most browsers will strip them out.

Comment: @ Cfreak = Yes i used it inside a $(document).ready  function

Comment: I want that the Div tag to Treats Everything inside it as a String (the HTML tag etc etc )

Answer (score 1):

Use text() instead of html().

```
var msg = $("#page").text();
alert(msg);
// Hellow World
```

Comment: I Want that the whole HTML tags which are present in the Div tag are shown :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the `<html>` and `<body>` tags like that - there can only be one of each, in very clearly defined positions. Did you want to use an iframe?

When the browser parses that page it'll ignore the inner `<html>` and `<body>` tags.

If you want to have a page within a page, you'll need to use an [`<iframe>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp).

Comment: Isnt there any other way except for an iframe ?

Comment: Well, a good old `<frameset>` could achieve a similar result, but I'd avoid it. But it's invalid HTML to have multiple tags like that.

Comment: I am using a PHP function to write the content of the inner division ? ( the HTML tags are comming from the PHP function file_get_contents() ) How can i display that in a IFRAME

Comment: I am trying not to use an Iframe because my JavaScript is not working in the Iframe

Comment: You need an iframe if you need there to be a complete page inside another page. If you're having problems with the JavaScript in that iframe then that's a different question. But start from that basis.

Comment: can i call an Iframe like this ?  <iframe id="frame" src="load.php?sinput="<?php $_GET["sinput"]; ?> > </iframe>

Comment: @Adi That depends what load.php is doing and what $_GET["sinput"] is. I think you need to be asking a different question though.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use html tag inside html

Preferably use Iframe inside html to write html inside html

You can use Iframes like this

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <font face="verdana,arial" size="3">
    <div align="center">
    <p>
        <a href="http://www.altavista.com" target="iframe1">AltaVista.com</a> |
        <a href="http://www.aol.com" target="iframe1">AOL.com</a> |
        <a href="http://www.lycos.com" target="iframe1">Lycos.com</a> |
        <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="iframe1">Yahoo.com</a>

    <p>
    <iframe name="iframe1" width="600" height="400" src="http://www.stackoverflow.com" frameborder="yes" scrolling="yes">
    </iframe>
    <p>

</font>
</div> 
<!--name="iframe1"
- Set all links to target the iframe1 name when you want the contents of the iframe to change from links on the originating page.

width="600" - Width of the iframe

height="400" - Height of the iframe * Width and height can be expressed in pixels or percent

src="http://www.yahoo.com" - Initial page that will fill in the iframe

frameborder="yes" - Border around the iframe is displayed by default

scrolling="yes" - Allow scrollbars around the iframe for navigation Vaild values are yes, no and auto

align="" - Valid entries are left and right left is set by default
-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am using a PHP function to write the content of the inner division ? ( the HTML tags are comming from the PHP function file_get_contents() ) How can i display that in a IFRAME ?

Comment: I am trying not to use an Iframe because Java Scripts is not working in the Iframe

Comment: You can use javascript inside iframes check out this link http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/Working-with-IFRAME-in-JavaScript/1/

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to avoid an `<iframe>` (which has it's own issues) and still use proper html, put the content as the value of a hidden `<textarea>`. Then you can use `.val()`.

Comment: I am using a PHP function to write the content of the inner division ? ( the HTML tags are comming from the PHP function file_get_contents() ) How can i display that in a IFRAME ?

Comment: My suggestion would be to add php code to remove everything before body and after /body in the function that inserts the contents.

Comment: You won't be able to display that in an iframe as described. Try using a textarea. `<textarea id="page_content" name="page_content" value="<%= file_get_contents() %>">`. To display it in an iframe, you'd need another url that just renders the file_get_contents() html and then you'd set the src attribute of the iframe to this url.

Comment: The textarea wont display the text as HTML . Thats the problem :)